# Python dataframe custom apply function

Tags: python, dataframe

I would like to do below in python using dataframe and custom apply function.

```
Month,1,2,3,4,5

Oct 2018,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,NaN

Nov 2018,0.5,1.0,1.5,NaN,NaN
```

First row is column headers. I would like to take each row and do a linear fit and populate slope and intercept into a separate column. For example, "Oct 2018" row has `x:[1,2,3,4],y:[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4]` should give `slope=0.1` and `intercept=0.0` whereas "Nov 2018" row has `x:[1,2,3], y:[0.5,1.0,1.5]` should give `slope=0.5` and `intercept=0.0`.

I am getting x values from column names. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_slope_interscept(x):
    # Need two valid points to determine slope and interscept
    first_index = x[1:,].first_valid_index()
    second_index = x[first_index+1:,].first_valid_index()
    x1, x2, y1, y2 = first_index, second_index, x[first_index], x[second_index]
    slope = (y2-y1)/ (x2-x1)
    interscept = y2 - slope*x2
    return [slope, interscept]

df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(get_slope_interscept(x), index=['slope', 'interscept']), axis=1)
```

This will also handle the case if there are invalid NaNs ahead in the row.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a new Slope column by using `.stack` and doing a `.groupby`of the month with a key thing being doing a `.sum()`, doing a `.rename` of the columns and using `.eval` to calculate the slope. Finally, send the values to a list in order to set it back to the newly created 'Slope' column. For an intercept column you can just set the intercept is zero.

Data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'Month':['Oct', 'Nov'],
                   1: [0.1,0.5],
                   2: [0.2,1.0],
                   3: [0.3,1.5],
                   4: [0.4,np.NaN],
                   5: [np.NaN,np.NaN]})
```

Code:

```
df['Slope'] = pd.DataFrame(df.set_index('Month').stack()).reset_index().groupby('Month').sum().rename(columns={'level_1' : 'x', 0 : 'y'}).eval('Slope = y / x')['Slope'].to_list()
```

Output:

```
df

    Month   1   2   3   4   5   Slope
0   Oct     0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 NaN 0.5
1   Nov     0.5 1.0 1.5 NaN NaN 0.1
```